# How can I increment nested dynamic values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a database that's loosely created which has a key called `website`. Within this `website` object I will have multiple objects, one for each dynamically created website. An example of how the database could look would be

```
website: {
    google.com: {
        count: 19,
        like: {huge: 9, normal: 10},
        follow: {big: 11, small: 8}
    },
    facebook.com: {
        count: 1,
        like: {huge: 1},
        follow: {big: 1}
    }
}
```

So websites is initially an empty object and the more that happens, more random websites will be added (google, facebook being the example)

Now, I want the values inside incremented by 1 when I get a hit for those values, so for example

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate({"_id": id}, {
website: {
    [query.name]: { $inc : { //query.name is the dynamic name that'll be given
        count: 1, //I want this count value incremented by one
        like: {
            [query.like]: 1 //query.like would be either huge or normal or something that's not available yet, in which case it would be created with a value of 1. If it exists I want the value incremented by one.
        },
        follow: {
            [query.follow]: 1 //query.follow would be either big or small or something that's not available yet, in which case it would be created with a value of 1. If it exists I want the value incremented by one.
        }
    }}
}
}, function(err, result){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

But this isn't working, it gives me an error saying "Error: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$inc' in 'website.[dynamic website name].$inc' is not valid for storage."

I tried putting the $inc in a few other places but I got about the same message.

Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the dot notation when you want to refer to nested fields so your JS code should look like this:

```js
let query = { name: "google.com", like: "huge", follow: "big" };

let update = {
   $inc: {
      [`website.${query.name}.count`]: 1,
      [`website.${query.name}.like.${query.like}`]: 1,               
      [`website.${query.name}.follow.${query.follow}`]: 1
   }
}

console.log(update);
```

You can try if that works. The problem is that you're using dots as subdocument names (`google.com`, `facebook.com`). The question is if MongoDB will be able to identify that key name is `google.com` as opposed to `{ google: { com: ... } }`. I would suggest removing those dots from field names. You can use underscore instead of dot like `google_com` - that will be much more safe.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly! I will also remember to take out the dots because as you said, mongo definitely won't be able to differentiate. Thanks again! :)